# ggplot geom_boxplot and plotting last value with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm new to R. I was trying to plot the last value of each variable in a data frame on top of a boxplot. Without success I was trying:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point(iris, aes(x=unique(iris$Species), y=tail(iris,n=1)))
```

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is

```
library(tidyverse)
iris1 <- iris %>% 
             group_by(Species) %>% 
             summarise(LastVal = last(Sepal.Length))
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length)) + 
          geom_boxplot() + 
          geom_point(data = iris1, aes(x = Species, y = LastVal))
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for your help. - Bill